# python program to write to json from input

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

I made a program in python3 that writes to json upon input from user. Program is running but includes slashes

i want it to be

Output:(written to a file sample.json)

```
 {
     "api" : api_key=4ewrs5798hoknlkmnnmhbvjgfd7" 
 }
```

But instead i get

Output:(written to a file sample.json)

```
{\"api\":\"api_key=4ewrs5798hoknlkmnnmhbvjgfd7\"}"
```

Backslash appears at every (") also indents are missing even if declared or not

```
import json
k1 = input("enter key")
k2 ='{"api" : ""api_key='+k1+'"}'

with open("sample.json", "w") as outfile: 
    json.dump(k2, outfile, indent=4)
print("success")
```

Comment: To use `json.dump` you need to have something that's actually a parsed JSON structure, of the sort that you would get from using `json.load` on a source file. If you have a plain string that happens to be valid JSON, then you can just write that like anything else. A .json file is *just a file*. The special thing is the JSON *data format*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem has to do with the quotations you are using in k2. A better way of doing this is to use dicts.

```
import json
k2 = {}
k2['api'] = "api_key=" + input("enter key")

with open("sample.json", "w") as outfile:
    json.dump(k2, outfile, indent=4)
print("success")
```